Prediction Interval for Rayleigh or Exponential parameter estimate
I am working with Rayleigh and Exponential random variables.  These have convenient closed form confidence intervals for their parameter estimator.  But now we are interested in making a statement of the form, "Given some experimental data, what can we expect w.r.t. the parameter estimate from future experiments?"  I understand that what I am asking for is a Prediction Interval on the MLE.
I initially thought this would be something like a confidence interval (CI) squared.  For example, "First experiment produced a 90% CI on $\hat{\sigma}$ = [1, 2].  So with probability 90% the true $\sigma$ is in that range, which means that 90% of similar experiments will produce a 90% CI that contains some part of the interval [1, 2]."  But there's a 10% probability that the true $\sigma$ is not in that interval, in which case ... well, I don't know.  But given how "nice" and Normal-adjacent the Exponential distribution is I suspect that there is a closed form expression for the Prediction Interval.  Can someone suggest one?
(I can verify a formula using Monte Carlo techniques, though a derivation might be even more helpful.  I haven't had success searching for answers because prediction intervals are so widely used to get future values in regression scenarios.)

Example problem statement:

Let $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda)$ where $\lambda$ is unknown.
An experiment to estimate $\lambda$ draws $n$ samples of $X$ and estimates $\hat{\lambda} = \bar{x}$.
Given the outcome of one experiment, $\hat{\lambda_1}$, find the 90% Prediction Interval for the value $\hat{\lambda_2}$ from repeating the experiment (with the same $n$).

To verify the Prediction Interval Formula via simulation, I will:

Set an arbitrary $\lambda^*$ and integer $n > 2$.
Conduct the first experiment: Draw $n$ samples from an Exponential RNG parameterized with $\lambda^*$.  Compute $\hat{\lambda_1} = \bar{x}$.
Using the Formula, compute the upper limit of the Prediction Interval, $\operatorname{PI}_{90\%}$.
Simulate repeated experiments and count the number of times that $\hat{\lambda_i} > \operatorname{PI}_{90\%}$.
The Formula is verified if that frequency converges towards 5%.


See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution

@JarleTufto thank you – good hint that led me to this paper which I'm working on deciphering....

Unfortunately, most of the literature (including the aforementioned paper) deals with order statistics.  This paper suggests that the prediction interval I want is a relatively simple function of the F distribution, but so far I haven't worked out a function that does it.

Jarle Tufto's comment on the F-distiribution gives you almost all you need.
The mean of $n$ iid samples from an exponential distribution with expectation $\lambda$ has a gamma distribution with shape $n$ and scale $\frac1n \lambda$ so expectation $\lambda$ again.  (If you had intended to use $\lambda$ as a rate parameter rather than a mean, just take its reciprocal, but essentially it cancels.)
Essentially you are interested in the ratio of two such gamma distributed random variables, which has an $F(2n,2n)$ distribution.
So using this, when $n=1$, you get a prediction interval of $[\frac1{19}\bar x, 19 \bar x]$, noting $\frac{0.95}{0.05}=19$, and as examples for larger $n$:

when $n=2$ your prediction interval is $[0.1565378\bar x, 6.3882329 \bar x]$
when $n=10$ your prediction interval is $[0.4707754\bar x, 2.1241552
 \bar x]$
when $n=100$ your prediction interval is $[0.7920178\bar x, 1.2625978
 \bar x]$

You should be able to confirm these results with simulations.  For example using R
ininterval <- function(n, meanofexponential, conf){
    xbar <- mean(rexp(n, 1/meanofexponential))
    predhigh <-  qf((1+conf)/2, 2*n, 2*n) * xbar 
    predlow <-   qf((1-conf)/2, 2*n, 2*n) * xbar 
    ybar <- mean(rexp(n, 1/meanofexponential))
    return( ybar > predlow & ybar < predhigh )
    }

set.seed(2024)
sims <- replicate(10^5, ininterval(n=10, meanofexponential=7, conf=0.90))
mean(sims)
# 0.9001

is very close to $90\%$, allowing for simulation noise.
The reason the F distribution works here is that although it is usually described as the distribution of the scaled ratio of two chi-square distributions,  the chi-squared distributions are also gamma distributions.  In the same way, you could, if you preferred, use suitable beta prime distributions rather than F distributions, and you would get the same results.
